# Reporting services searching in long list parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, parameters, reporting

I have a question for You.
I need an idea to search items in long list of parameters in sql reporting services.
For example there is a houndred of values in list of parameters to select and i have to choose some of them. There exists problem with finding these values because list is too big. 
Something searching by first couple letters would be great but probably it is impossible.
Now I really do not know how i could achieve smart method to find couple interested values from list of parameters.
Please help.

Comment: Are you talking about a user interface that a user could use to pick a couple of values from a (long) list of possible values for a parameter?

Comment: Long I mean big portion of data, and not in user interface. It would be great to choose these values before generating report. In neccesity it could by in user interface (some kind of sorting, filtering in real time) but before generetion would be better. I have an one idea. I could create my own assembly which it would make such searching and returning results in parameter list which is set before report generation. But i'd rather use another, faster and simpler approach.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still a little confused. The long list of parameter values is actually passed to the report? Who would choose these values, and how would they choose them if not through a user interface?

Comment: Sorry for my bads. I am new in reporting services and i do not know this environment well.
Yes, big portion of data is passed to the report as parameters. And it is provided before the view report button is clicked.
I have to make for user easy and kind serching in list of parameters like for example searching parameter by it's beginning letters

Comment: Are you using the Web or Windows report viewer?

Comment: Windows report viewer but i know what You mean.
power view?

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement, I have found an awesome article talking about this with detail solution:

Create a function in your database.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitParameterValues] (@InputString NVARCHAR(max), @SplitChar VARCHAR(5))
  RETURNS @ValuesList TABLE
  (
  param NVARCHAR(255)
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
  DECLARE @ListValue NVARCHAR(max)
  SET @InputString = @InputString + @SplitChar
  WHILE @InputString!= @SplitChar
  BEGIN
  SELECT @ListValue = SUBSTRING(@InputString , 1, (CHARINDEX(@SplitChar, @InputString)-1))
  IF (CHARINDEX(@SplitChar, @InputString) + len(@SplitChar))>(LEN(@InputString))
  BEGIN
  SET @InputString=@SplitChar
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
  SELECT @InputString = SUBSTRING(@InputString, (CHARINDEX(@SplitChar, @InputString) + len(@SplitChar)) , LEN(@InputString)-(CHARINDEX(@SplitChar, @InputString)+ len(@SplitChar)-1) )
  END
 INSERT INTO @ValuesList VALUES( @ListValue)
  END
  RETURN
  END
```

Use a procedure the get the Available Values, refer to the query below:

```
create PROCEDURE sp (@keyword nvarchar(50))
 AS
 SELECT     col
 FROM         table d
 inner join (SELECT [param] FROM SplitParameterValues (@keyword,',')) s on d.col like (s.[param]+'%')
```

Then create a parameter for giving keywords. Then add another cascading parameter based on the key words. For detail steps, please read the source article from the link below:

[[Forum FAQ]How do I add a search feature in the parameter with long drop down list?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8de6c783-9cb4-4b95-9be8-b59bc0049866/forum-faqhow-do-i-add-a-search-feature-in-the-parameter-with-long-drop-down-list?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This link is from Microsoft official forum. Even the link can be changed, we can still easily find it by googling the article title. I don't think it's good to copy an answer which is completely from another article

Comment: thanks for the link. it very quirky smart  :) I looove it